# How to create a Redis Cluster on AKS?

Tags: kubernetes, redis, azure-aks, bitnami

I'm trying to create a Redis Cluster on Azure AKS using Bitnami Helm Chart, but I can't get it working.

My cluster have two node pools, one running linux and the other running windows machines, so, I have to specify the nodeSelector attribute. My command is:

`helm install --set master.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"="linux"  --set slave.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"="linux" redis azure-marketplace/redis`

I got it from https://bitnami.com/stack/redis/helm

When I run the `helm install` the master node start running as expected, but the slave node fails. The message says:

> Warning    FailedMount    26s (x2 over 2m41s)    kubelet
> Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[redis-data], unattached volumes=[health redis-data config redis-tmp-conf default-token-p7zgf start-scripts]: timed out waiting for the condition

> Normal    SuccessfulAttachVolume    3s    attachdetach-controller
> AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-aXXXXXXc-aXXf-4XXe-bXX9-9xxxxxxxxx49"

> Warning    FailedMount        kubelet
> MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-aXXXXXXc-aXXf-4XXe-bXX9-9XXXXXXXXX49" : azureDisk - mountDevice:FormatAndMount failed with mount failed: exit status 32
> Mounting command: systemd-run
> Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/azure-disk/mounts/m38XXXXXX77 --scope -- mount -t ext4 -o defaults /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0 /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/azure-disk/mounts/m38XXXXXX77

> Output: Running scope as unit: run-ra32XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX7f2f7.scope
> mount: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/azure-disk/mounts/m38XXXXXX77: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

> Warning    FailedMount        kubelet
> MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-aXXXXXXc-aXXf-4XXe-bXX9-9XXXXXXXXX49" : azureDisk - mountDevice:FormatAndMount failed with mount failed: exit status 32

I tried many times without success.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the slave pod on the same node as where the Persistent Volume attached? We started using

```
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

In our storage classes to help avoid pod and pv instantiating on different hosts.

Followup: It appears in this scenario the chart is relying on the clusters default storage class which did not have the same node affinity rules as the deployment/statefulset objects. Additionally the cluster has a mix of workers from different operating systems (win, linux). The chart logic was expecting a linux os mount and encountered a windows host instead.

Comment: Hi Lance. Thanks for answering. I tryed to use param --set global.storageClass=default because in AKS, default storage class uses WaitForFirstClass BindingMode. But I had no success. Same error.

Comment: @AndySchmitt can you confirm if the pod is launching on the same node the pv was attached too?

Comment: Sorry Lance, I'm new to kubernetes. How can I confirm that?

Comment: Ohh I see... the slave pvc was bound to a windows node.

Comment: Between `kubectl describe pv <name>` and `kubectl describe pvc <claim name>` you should be able to discern where k8s is mounting

Comment: Lance, with your tip, I could make it work. It was awesome. Thank you very much.